# Argument of type 'typeof MsalService' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MsalService' in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, graphql

I am trying to create an object of a class in typescript /angular.
In my project there is a scenario i have to call from an export function to a method which is inside an another class in typescript

```
  const myObject = new TokenService(MsalService);
```

I am getting the following error. How to solve this error? i have been stuck here for about one whole day.

> Argument of type 'typeof MsalService' is not assignable to parameter
> of type 'MsalService'. Type 'typeof MsalService' is missing the
> following properties from type 'MsalService': instance, location,
> redirectHash, logger, and 13 more.ts(2345) graphql.module.ts(59, 37):
> Did you mean to use 'new' with this expression?

[image]

Actual class has a constructor

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So you have a method that you need to call, the best way to do this, is to make the method `static`. I just set the method as public to ensure its accessible outside the class, this is an optional step!

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MsalService {

  constructor() { }

   public static someMethod() {
        // do something...
   }

}
```

This means, you can call this method like

```
MsalService.someMethod()
```

There is no need to initialize the class in-order to access the method, this will save you the hassle of initializing it!

We cannot initialize services like this (`new TokenService(MsalService)`), because services are singletons in angular which are handled through dependency injection so converting the method to a static method and passing the necessary details as arguments will work fine.

Comment: Hi @naren thanks for the reply. Actually i sorted it in  a different way. since i am new to angular i struggled to find a solution after a deep research the following solution worked for me . I just passed it as a parameter `**export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink,tokenService:TokenService): **`